# Determine the existence of $\alpha \in S_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

Given $S_{10}$, determine whether there is an cycle $\alpha \in S_{10}$ for which $\alpha^k =(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)(7\ 8)(9\ 10)$ for  some $k\in \Bbb N$.

I am thinking of using the closure of $S_{10}$ as a group and that $\alpha^k$ is in itself an element of the group and therefore there should exist $\alpha$ for which it is true?

But I definitely do not know the correctness of my idea. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Think of something like $\alpha = (1 \ 3\ 5\ 7\ 9\ 2\ 4\ 6\ 8\ 10)$?

Comment: I already have some specific cycles that will satisfy the given condition. But, is there a way somehow to determine its existence other than specifying its value?